# Im trying to convert a pdf to an image but i keep getting this error wand.exceptions.DelegateError

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert a pdf into an image using wand.image but keep getting this error:

```
wand.exceptions.DelegateError: FailedToExecuteCommand `"gswin32c.exe" -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r300x300"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/angel/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-32720Q2HUSQhwtDBC%d" "-fC:/Users/angel/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-32720YmkuoFhQVf-T" "-fC:/Users/angel/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-32720i-5wg9xQf3yI"' (The system cannot find the file specified.) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/475
```

My code is below:

```
from wand.image import Image as wi

    pdf = wi(filename='Maxis Mar Copy.pdf',resolution=300)
    pdfImage = pdf.convert('jpeg')

    i = 1
    for img in pdfImage.sequence:
        page = wi(image=img)
        page.save(filename=str(i)+".jpg")
        i +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is here

> (The system cannot find the file specified.)

Have you installed wand correctly?

As an alternative, you could try something like [this](https://mtyurt.net/post/2019/multipage-pdf-to-jpeg-image-in-python.html)